# Can someone help explain why I get this 'Value is not what was expected' error with Javascript?

Tags: javascript

I'm working on beefing up my Javascript skills with some katas on codewars. Here is one such kata:

> At a job interview, you are challenged to write an algorithm to check if a given string, s, can be formed from two other strings, part1 and part2.
>
> The restriction is that the characters in part1 and part2 are in the same order as in s.
>
> The interviewer gives you the following example and tells you to figure out the rest from the given test cases.
>
> For example:
>
> 'codewars' is a merge from 'cdw' and 'oears':
>
> ```
>    s:  c o d e w a r s   = codewars
> part1:  c   d   w         = cdw
> part2:    o   e   a r s   = oears
> ```

Here is my solution that I am working on:

```
function presentInString(element, index, array) {
    return string.includes(element);
}

function isMerge(s, part1, part2) {
    string = s;
    var mergedParts = (part1 + part2).split('');
    mergedParts.every(presentInString);
}
```

My approach is simple, I get passed in a string `'codewars'` and with parts  `'cdw'` and `'oears'` The above methods should return true because all of the characters are in the string. but I keep getting a `Value is not what was expected` error. I must be using the `.every` method wrong but I'm not sure how. I pretty much based it off of the Javascript MDN docs. Could someone pinpoint what I'm doing wrong?

- It's a kata in progress by the way and I haven't tested all edge cases. Some cases will fail.

Additionally, do I have to create another function to pass into `.every`? I would rather just right the logic in the scope of `.every` instead of writing another function to pass off to.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't vouch for your overall algorithm, but the problem with `isMerge` is that it doesn't use the return value of `every` and doesn't return anything. You probably wanted:

```
return mergedParts.every(presentInString);
```

as the last line, which makes the return value of `isMerge` whatever `every` returns (`true` if `presentInString` returns a truthy value for each element, `false` if it doesn't).

Comment: Thanks @T.J. Crowder. That is something I need to get used to moving from Ruby. I appreciate you pointing that out. I'll accept once the time restriction is lifted.

Comment: @DanRubio: Ah, of course! Ruby and CoffeeScript both do that. I did think it looked a bit like that.