# Confused about the `return` statement in javascript. Explanation needed

Tags: javascript

I posted a question not too long ago this morning regarding a kata that I was trying to solve. In that question, (found here if interested [Kata Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40633773/can-someone-help-explain-why-i-get-this-value-is-not-what-was-expected-error-w/40633856?noredirect=1#comment68500623_40633856)) I needed to add a `return` statement to my function so that I would avoid the following error `Value is not what was expected`.

Now I have my second iteration of my kata solution to try out and here it is:

```
function isMerge(s, part1, part2) {
  var pointer = 0
  splitString = s.split('');
  splitString.forEach(function(character) {
    if (part1.includes(character) || part2.includes(character)) {
      pointer++;
      return true;
    } else { 
      return false;
    }
  });
}

isMerge('codewars','cdw','oears')
```

I am still getting `Value is not what was expected` errors when I try to execute the code and this time I'm confused as to why in particular this happens.

For starters, taken from the MDN guide

> The return statement ends function execution and specifies a value to be returned to the function caller.
>
> **expression**
>   The expression to return. If omitted, undefined is returned instead.

Look at my `if/else` logic I am specifying a `return true` and `return false` condition in my `forEach` loop to see if all the chars from `part1` and `part2` are in the string. I am returning something so why is it that I have a `Value is not what was expected`?.

Second of all, by definition of the `return` statement, the function is supposed to stop when it reaches that keyword. However, when I place a `console.log(character)` in the logic, I can see on my console that all of the characters are being outputted so the function is not breaking at all when `return true` is executed. Why is that?

Third, I am confused as to when to use the `return` keyword in general. Consider these examples from the MDN docs for `ForEach`.

Example 1:

```
function logArrayElements(element, index, array) {
  console.log('a[' + index + '] = ' + element);
}

// Notice that index 2 is skipped since there is no item at
// that position in the array.
[2, 5, , 9].forEach(logArrayElements);
// logs:
// a[0] = 2
// a[1] = 5
// a[3] = 9
```

Example 2:

```
function Counter() {
  this.sum = 0;
  this.count = 0;
}
Counter.prototype.add = function(array) {
  array.forEach(function(entry) {
    this.sum += entry;
    ++this.count;
  }, this);
  // ^---- Note
};

var obj = new Counter();
obj.add([2, 5, 9]);
obj.count
// 3 
obj.sum
// 16
```

Not a single `return` statement to in these examples.

Now look at this `.every` example.

```
function isBigEnough(element, index, array) { 
  return element >= 10; 
} 

[12, 5, 8, 130, 44].every(isBigEnough);
```

And finally, from my previous question, I need to add a second `return` statement like this to avoid the value error.

```
function isBigEnough(element, index, array) { 
  return element >= 10; 
} 

function whenToUseReturn(array) {
  return array.every(isBigEnough);
}

whenToUseReturn([12, 5, 8, 130, 44]);
```

So....... in conclusion, for my original function that started this how am I supposed to exit the loop when I reach `false` and return it and likewise when all the characters are in the string, how do I return a 'cumulative' true and avoid a Value error. I hope this makes sense and I can clarify with edits to better illustrate my point.

Comment: The `return` statement returns from the callback you pass to `forEach`, *not* from `isMerge`. `isMerge` doesn't contain a `return` statement, hence it returns `undefined`.

Comment: And FWIW, *iff* the return statements inside the callback would return from `isMerge`, it would always return in the first iteration of the array, so that wouldn't be very useful anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I am returning something so why is it that I have a Value is not what was expected?.

The `return` statement returns from the callback you pass to `forEach`, *not* from `isMerge`. `return` statements don't cross function boundaries. `isMerge` doesn't contain a return statement, hence it returns `undefined`. If we rewrite the function slightly it might become clearer:

```
function doSomething(part1, part2) {
  return function(character) {
    if (part1.includes(character) || part2.includes(character)) {
      return true;
    } else { 
      return false;
    }
  }
}

function isMerge(s, part1, part2) {
  splitString = s.split('');
  splitString.forEach(doSomething(part1, part2));
}

isMerge('codewars','cdw','oears')
```

This is equivalent to your code. As you can see, there is no `return` statement in `isMerge`.

> Not a single return statement to in these examples.

There are no `return` statements in the `forEach` examples because `forEach` *doesn't do anything with the return value of the callback*, so there is no point in returning anything.

`forEach` is just a different way to iterate over an array, but it doesn't produce a value like `reduce` or `every`.

> how am I supposed to exit the loop when I reach false and return it and likewise when all the characters are in the string, how do I return a 'cumulative' true and avoid a Value error.

You cannot exit a `forEach` "loop". If you have to stop the iteration early, you need to use a normal `for` (`for/in`, `for/of`) loop.

To return and *produce* a value, you can use your original solution that uses `every`.

Answer (score 1):

My friend, since you decided to go the "callback way" using .each and the like, you should consider using callbacks, since you cannot return anything in this case. If you do not wish to go the callback way, just use standard javascript, such as:

```
splitString.forEach(function(character) {
```

Replace with

```
for(var i = 0 ; i < splitString.length; i++){
```

And now you can return. Using "each" to loop an array is just plain unnecessary and prevents you to return.

Comment: His example just proved this.

Comment: Absolutely correct. In ES6, `forEach` is dead and shouldn't be used. Use `for (let char of string)`.

Comment: *""you should consider actually using callbacks"* What does that mean in this context?

Comment: @georg: `forEach` skips holes, `for/of` doesn't, so they are not equivalent (in this particular case they are).

Comment: @FelixKling: "arrays with holes" is not something one should be using either ;)) Too bad many people stick to this old forEach-reduce-whatever stuff and are reluctant to use cleaner and simpler ES6 loops/blocks/iterators.

Comment: *"you should consider using callbacks"* still doesn't make sense to me. They *are* passing a callback to `forEach`, so what else do you expect them to do?

Comment: @georg, This was taken from Understanding ES6 https://leanpub.com/understandinges6/read. "ECMAScript 5 added forEach() to arrays to make working on each item in an array without setting up a for loop easier. The method proved popular among developers, and so the same method is available on sets and works the same way." This excerpt was from the Sets section but it seems like ES6 encourages it. Is there a best practices reference for ES6 that is official? I can't tell if the MDN docs are updated for ES6 or not.

Comment: @DanRubio: *"Is there a best practices reference for ES6 that is official?"* If by that you mean whether there is such a reference endorsed by the TC39 committee (which is working on the ECMAScript standard), the answer is no.